# SSRS Sharepoint Integrated Mode: Where's my recursive parameter?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, reporting-services

Could someone tell me why the SSRS web service ReportService2005.asmx has a recursive parameter on ListChildren while the Sharepoint integrated mode version ReportService2006.asmx does not?

**ReportService2005:**

```
public CatalogItem[] ListChildren (
    string Item,
    bool Recursive
)
```

***Ref:*** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.listchildren.aspx

**ReportService2006:**

```
public CatalogItem[] ListChildren (
    string Item
)
```

***Ref:*** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2006.reportingservice2006.listchildren.aspx

If I want to ListChildren in sharepoint integrated mode, I assume I have to recurse myself?

Reasoning behind the removal of this parameter?

Google showing nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by writing my own code to recursively retreive the directories I need.